# Which of the following are valid JSON documents?

Tags: json

Which of the following are valid JSON documents?

1. `{“name”:”Fred Flintstone”;”occupation”:”Miner”;”wife”:”Wilma”}`
2. `{“title”:”Star Wars”, “quotes”:[“Use The Force”,”These are not the Droids you are looking for”],”director”:”George Lucas”}`
3. `{}`
4. `{“city”:”New York”, “population”, 7999034, boros:{“queens”, “manhattan”, “staten island”, “the bronx”, “brooklyn”}}`
5. `{“a”:1, “b”:{“b”:1, “c”:”foo”, “d”:”bar”, “e”:[1,2,4]}}`

Comment: 6.  Since this appears to be homework, what do *you* think the answers are, and why?

Comment: first I was confused I thought answer is only option 3 n it was wrong answer ..so again I went through d video... json uses { "key" :"value"} format and "[ ]" is used to represent array ...and its separated by "," ....from that answer is  2,3 and 5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question.

Comment: The ones that are valid are the ones that follow documented JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously homework, so I will try to help you to come to the correct solution yourself, not just hand it to you.

1. Look up which character is used to separate the individual key/value pairs from each other in a JSON document. One of the documents is using the wrong character.
2. Look up the difference between objects and arrays in JSON. What's the difference and which characters are used to mark the beginning and end of either? The author of one of the documents tried to create an array, but uses the syntax for objects.

The [official JSON specification](http://json.org/) can serve as a reference for you.